# Android Service - Service and Service - Activity bidirectional communication

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app targeting SDK21. At the moment I need to glue some pieces of logic and I can't seem to find a way to do it. The app has multiple activities and two `Services` which run in the background, one of which is exported.

The logic flow should be as follows:

1. Local service listens for Bluetooth connections. After a connection is established, each incoming message is packed into an object. The party at the other side of the connection is waiting for a reply.
2. For each incoming message, the created object needs to be sent to the exported service, which will eventually reply.
3. The exported service needs to start an activity (edit: included in my application) and wait for the user to perform an action. Depending on the result of the action, the service will generate a reply and send it back to the local service (a reply is generated in all possible cases), which in turn should send it (in byte[] format) back to the other party.

Local service <---> Exported service <---> Activity

Assuming that doing this is possible, how should I approach it?

Comment: Why do you have 2 services?

Comment: Because one is meant to be used by any application and one is only specific to how my app works and how it uses that exported service.

Comment: So I could write an app that uses your exported service? And how would then work this? It would open my app's activity?

Comment: No, it would start an activity included in my app package. The service relies on the activity to let the user confirm the action that is going to be performed by it.

Comment: So why is it exported?

Comment: Because other apps may want to use it. The activity it starts is just part of how the service does what it does. This service takes an incoming message and after the user interaction is complete it creates a reply which must reach the sender.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104342/discussion-between-gavriel-and-r-g).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You'll need to use AIDL, which is a pain in the neck  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html  AIDL is the method that Android uses to have internal services and apps talk to each other, such as the keyboard talking to the active application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. the local service (or the "other app") creates a PendingIntent, prepared in such a way, that it can be used to send back the response at the end (using direct class, so the response is only received by the recipient, no need to broadcast it)
2. The message object and the PendingIntent is sent in a Bundle to the exported Activity
3. The activity asks the user, and depending on the user interaction it sends the message + the interaction + the PendingIntent to the service. This is needed, because it makes it easy to send the user interaction to the service.
4. Service does the calculations and prepares the response
5. Service sends back the response using the PendingIntent

You could also do:

2b. Client sends PendingIntent and message to exported service,

3b. Exported service starts activity

4b. Activity sends another intent to the exported service that includes the message + the user's choice

5b. Exported service prepares the response

6b. Exported service sends back the response in a Bundle using the PendingIntent